# Is this a good way to create unique folders based on modified dates?

Tags: bash, sorting, date, directory, unique

I have a folder full of images. I'd like to create folders for each based on when that image (or file) was modified. Is this a good way to do that in bash? The code works but I'm still a novice and not sure if there are better ways.

```
ls -l | sort -k8n -k6M -k7n | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f6-8 | uniq | sed '/^$/d'| parallel -j 24 date --date={} +"%Y-%m-%d"| parallel -j 24 mkdir {}
```

Explanation of code:

1. `ls -l` #find files and tell me modified date.
2. `sort -k8n -k6M -k7n` # sort values by column 8 (format numeric) then 6 (format is Month) then 7 (format numeric).
3. `tr -s ' '` # truncate all spaces into one spaces.
4. `cut -d ' ' -f6-8` # cut the text by the delimiter " " (i.e., space) and save columns 6-8.
5. `uniq` #save only unique values
6. `sed '/^$/d'` #remove empty lines.
7. `parallel -j 24 date --date={} +"%Y-%m-%d"` #take input and parallel process into 24 jobs. Then convert the date input (coming from {}) into a YYYY-MM-DD format.
8. `parallel -j 24 mkdir {}` #create 24 jobs that create folders based on output from previous command ({}).

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: [why not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) is good reading.

Comment: Personally, I'd do this in a quick perl or tcl script, not straight up shell.

Comment: Oh right! I forgot about parsing ls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of simpler, less error prone ways to do this. If you have the GNU version of [`date(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html), for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nullglob
declare -A mtimes
# Adjust pattern as needed
for file in *.{png,jpg}; do
    mtimes[$(date -r "$file" +'%Y-%m-%d')]=1
done
mkdir "${!mtimes[@]}"
```

This uses a `bash` associative array to store all the timestamps to use to create new directories from and then makes them all at once with a single `mkdir`.

---

And since I mentioned preferring to do it in something other than pure shell in a comment, a `tcl` one-liner:

```
tclsh8.6 <<'EOF'
file mkdir {*}[lsort -unique [lmap file [glob -nocomplain -type f *.{png,jpg}] { clock format [file mtime $file] -format %Y-%m-%d }]]
EOF
```

or `perl`:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -e '$mtimes{strftime q/%Y-%m-%d/, localtime((stat)[9])} = 1 for (glob q/*.{png,jpg}/); mkdir for keys %mtimes'
```

Both of these have the advantage of not needing a specific implementation of `date` (The `-r` option isn't POSIX; not sure how widely supported it is outside of the GNU coreutils version), or `bash` 4+ (An issue if you're using, say, a Mac (I *think* they still come with perl, at least until the next OS X version or two)).